# tablesorter not sorting properly after changing table element using content editable widget

Tags: widget, contenteditable, tablesorter

I got tablesorter working fine.
Added the content editable widget and with a bit of fiddling, got that working too.

There is an odd anomaly tho'

If I edit an element and then sort, the element sorts as if it still had its initial value.

For example value AAA initially sorts to the top, but if it is changed to ZZZ and then I sort descending it doesn't appear with the Zs. If I then sort ascending, it is back at the top of the list above the Bs!

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the cache isn't being updated. I see everything works in the [main demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-editable.html). Please share the code you're using so we can help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Here are the log files - It must be my code.

Comment: looked at the log, none of the widget config options are recognised 
• jquery.tablesorter.js:2545 Tablesorter Warning! "table.config.widgetOptions.columns_tfoot" option not recognized


Then all the widgets except editable are updated and applied
• jquery.tablesorter.js:2061 Updating zebra widget

• jquery.tablesorter.js:2067 Completed applying zebra widget (335 ms)

etc - then ...

• jquery.tablesorter.js:2104 "editable" was enabled, but the widget code has not been loaded!

Comment: any ideas anyone?

Comment: Each widget needs to be loaded separately. The core `jquery.tablesorter.js` only includes the zebra widget. The `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js` file includes only a few widgets (columns, filter, resizable, sticky, storage and uitheme).